# running a ruby script in notepad++

Tags: ruby, notepad++, command-prompt

I've pasted the following code in notepad:

```rb
puts ("enter a number")
x = gets.to_i
puts ("enter a second number")
y = gets.to_i
result = x + y
puts result
```

I've also created the following batch file:

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb" "%1"
pause
```

When running the prog I get the following response in the command line:

```
enter a number
C:/Users/Asus/ruby/helloworld.rb:2:in `gets': Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - $(C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb) (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Users/Asus/ruby/helloworld.rb:2:in `gets'
        from C:/Users/Asus/ruby/helloworld.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does it work outside your batch file when running `ruby helloworld.rb`?

Comment: Stefan - yes, i've tried to run it without batch- i"m entering two numbers and i can't see the result -the command line window goes off immediately

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like the stdin file stream is not being passed to ruby, or perhaps it's already closed.

Comment: @tarry100 how exactly do you run the Ruby script?

Comment: Go to Run - run and paste - C:\Users\Asus\ruby\runruby.bat $(C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb)

Comment: It may be that your editor is not in *interactive* mode, and as such `$stdin` is already closed. This means `gets` will not work. Many editors run code like this expecting only output, not requiring input.

Comment: @tarry100 that seems to be the command to run the batch file. How did you run it without the batch file?

Comment: tadman- in cmd line prompt it works well - how can i change notepad++ to interactive mode?

Comment: Stefan - Run- C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb

Comment: Well, thanks guys - looks like i found the answer

Comment: @tarry100 feel free to post your solution, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I meant to say that previous post saying that $sdtin does not work - looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on windows:

Make you batch file look like:

```
@echo off
"C:\your\path\to\ruby.exe" "%1"
pause
```

Edit a ruby file in Notepad++ and **save** it.
Enter the following in the dialog box from the menu "Run/Run..."

```
"C:\your\path\to\batchfile.bat" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Alternatively you can call ruby directly from the Run/Run... but you will need to put a pause at the end of your script, eg:

```
"C:\your\path\to\ruby.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

And your code should do something like:

```
puts "Enter a number"
x = gets.to_i
puts "Enter a second number"
y = gets.to_i
result = x + y
puts "The result of #{x} + #{y} = #{result}"

puts "\nPress enter to exit"
gets
```

Once you are comfortable with that then maybe set up a Run/Run... to run Rake tasks in your project

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your contribution.                                                                 Interestingly, now when I run this ruby script on notepad++ - VSCode is launched with the same code and it can be run in terminal.  I run this in notepad++ with the same batch as you indicated - i get the same error

Comment: Hello @tarry100 - If your batch file is as in your post above and still contains 
`"C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb" "%1"` then you are not running ruby.  You are opening the 'rb' file - it is probably associated with VSCode which opens it.   You need to use the ruby interpreter to run your ruby script.   So make sure your batch file has `"C:\your\path\to\ruby.exe" "%1"`.  HTH

Comment: Would the following be right, Andrew? @echo off
"C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe" "C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb" "%1"
pause